# Problems with Maze image 2d Array

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing

I have to write a program to solve a maze image and I decided to pass the image into something more easy to read, so I convert the image into a 2D array like follow:
 # : blackwalls 
' : white spaces 
R : the start (I know where is and is read) 
B : the end (I know where is and is blue)

The problem is that I represented each pixel in a character so I have a 441 x 441 2d array.
Here my questino: How I can simplify the number of elements in my 2d array without losing the maze proportions?

I have this:

```
 # # # # # # # 
 # ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '       
 # ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '       
 # ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
```

and i want this

```
 # # # # # # # 
 #       
 # ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '       
 #
```

I only want to delete the White spaces, that way i don't have to check each space, the problem is I have to determine how much white spaces(') I have to delete for each column and each row.

Comment: Check out how I read and built the maze terrain in this project: http://hexgridutilities.codeplex.com/ I think everything you need is in MazeMap.cs.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, can you explain me a little what are they doing in the MazeMap.cs class please?

Comment: Can you post two example images that you need to solve for? What the best approach to take is (e.g. how complex you need to write it) depends on what kind of maze you need to solve

Comment: Thanks for your help Im going to use the A* algorithm to solve de maze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Lot of work I was able to solve problem by using the A* algorithm, this was a solution for my case but there is a lot of algorithm that can be used to solve a maze image:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for, but if you are  trying to reduce the size of the array representing your maze you could use a jagged array.  At least for one of the dimensions.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca(v=vs.110).aspx

You can then replace several repeating values with a single value and a count.

```
Original: 
 # # # # # # # 
 # ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
 # ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
 # ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 

Jagged:
 # 7
 # ' 9
 # ' 9
 # ' 9
```

Comment: I know where is the start point, and the "'" symbols are the places that I can go then I can start checking each position (up, down, right and left), if there is a # it means I can't go to that place.

Comment: @Patashu see Moises's comment.  It just changes how you store the data, not how you use it.

Comment: I read all the image Pixel by pixel, if is black I store a # if is white "'".

Answer (score 0):

Here are the key parts of how I implemented my MazeMap. It is deigned for a hex grid, so the connectivity is slightly off from an orthogonal grid.

```
public sealed class MazeMap : MapDisplay {
  protected override string[]   Board { get { return _board; } }
  string[] _board = new string[] {
    ".............|.........|.......|.........|.............",
       /* many similar lines omitted */
    ".............................|.......|.....|..........."
  };

  public override bool  IsPassable(ICoordsUser coords) { 
    return IsOnBoard(coords)  &&  this[coords].Elevation == 0; 
  }

  public override IMapGridHex this[ICoordsCanon coords] { 
    get {return this[coords.User];} 
  }
  public override IMapGridHex this[ICoordsUser  coords] { get {
    return new GridHex(Board[coords.Y][coords.X], coords);
  } }

  public struct GridHex : IMapGridHex {
    internal static MapDisplay MyBoard { get; set; }

    public GridHex(char value, ICoordsUser coords) : this() { Value = value; Coords = coords; }

    IBoard<IGridHex> IGridHex.Board           { get { return MyBoard; } }
    public IBoard<IMapGridHex> Board          { get { return MyBoard; } }
    public ICoordsUser         Coords         { get; private set; }
    public int                 Elevation      { get { return Value == '.' ? 0 : 1; } }
    public int                 ElevationASL   { get { return Elevation * 10;   } }
    public int                 HeightObserver { get { return ElevationASL + 1; } }
    public int                 HeightTarget   { get { return ElevationASL + 1; } }
    public int                 HeightTerrain  { get { return ElevationASL + (Value == '.' ? 0 : 10); } }
    public char                Value          { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<NeighbourHex> GetNeighbours() {
      var @this = this;
      return NeighbourHex.GetNeighbours(@this).Where(n=>@this.Board.IsOnBoard(n.Hex.Coords));
    }
  }
}
```

Note the definition of `this` about half way down. This allows an instance of MaxeMap to be access like an array of `GridHex` structs.

The ICoordsUser and ICoordsCanon interfaces support hex-grid operations in rectangular or oblique (ie axes at 120 degrees) respectively, with automatic conversion from one to the other; this is unnecessary on a orthogonal grid, where it is sufficient to pass in a `Point` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your help Im going to use the A* algorithm to solve de maze